# php loop over multidimensional array can combine same key/value into new array element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am getting some data out of mysql into an array like this

```
array(
    [0] = array(
        'code' => '123456',
        'title' => 'something',
        'price' => '2.00',
        'other_value' => '555555'
    ),
    [1] = array(
        'code' => '123456',
        'title' => 'something',
        'price' => '2.00',
        'other_value' => '666666'
    ),
    [2] = array(
        'code' => '234567',
        'title' => 'something else',
        'price' => '3.00',
        'other_value' => '333333'
    ),
    [3] = array(
        'code' => '345678',
        'title' => 'another thing',
        'price' => '4.00',
        'other_value' => NULL
    ),
)
```

what i need to do is for each row, if the key *code* appears more than once, merge the rows into one but create a new array for the *other_value* like so

```
array(
    [0] = array(
        'code' => '123456',
        'title' => 'something',
        'price' => '2.00',
        'other_value' => array(
            [0] => '555555',
            [1] => '666666'
        )
    ),
    [1] = array(
        'code' => '234567',
        'title' => 'something else',
        'price' => '3.00',
        'other_value' => '333333'
    ),
    [2] = array(
        'code' => '345678',
        'title' => 'another thing',
        'price' => '4.00',
        'other_value' => NULL
    ),
)
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I did think about looping over the each row and checking for existence of thtat key/value then do something if it exists.

Comment: I'd do it on mysql level with [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for `other_value`.

Comment: are you merging only on `code` or the other 2 should be considered too (`title` and `price`) ? for example if you have another entry with same `code` as 1st but other `title` and other `price`, would you expect the `title` and the `price` to be arrays as well?

Answer (score 1):

@AdRock i hope you want to merge array in case of when 'code' will be same, if this is so then try below one:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
            array(
                'code' => '123456',
                'title' => 'something',
                'price' => '2.00',
                'other_value' => '555555'
            ),
            array(
                'code' => '123456',
                'title' => 'something',
                'price' => '2.00',
                'other_value' => '666666'
            ),
           array(
                'code' => '234567',
                'title' => 'something else',
                'price' => '3.00',
                'other_value' => '333333'
            ),
            array(
                'code' => '345678',
                'title' => 'another thing',
                'price' => '4.00',
                'other_value' => NULL
            )
        );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);// array before
$isExist = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value["code"], $isExist)){
        $getKey = array_search($value["code"], $isExist);
        $arr[$getKey]["other_value"] = array($arr[$getKey]["other_value"], $value["other_value"]);
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    else{
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    }
    $isExist[$key] = $value["code"];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($arr));// array after
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I would suggest is to loop through the array and store the value of `code` into a new array and store the entire result set into a new array. With each iteration, check whether the value is present or not in the `code` value stored array. And if value found then in that case, get the key of the `code` array and use the same key for the result array and store it inside the `other_value`. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over the array and creating a new array using the 'code' values as keys might be the simplest method. In that case you can check if the key allready exists.

```
$new_array=array();

foreach($array as $part){
  $code_as_key = $part['code'];
  //if code allready in the new array, just add a new value
  if( isset($new_array[$code_as_key]) ){
     $new_array[$code_as_key]['other_value'][] = $part['other_value'];
     }
  //else add the new code
  else{
     $new_array[$code_as_key]=$part;
     }
}
//re-index the new array, starting from key 0
$new_array=array_values($new_array);
```

Comment: Ah, I now see 'other value' isn't always an array, so you have to check for that to.

Comment: other_value will be null if the code doesn't exist in tableB